Particle to Blob to Surface Settlement
I want to create this type of animation in underwater scene. Here is the idea:

The polymer will be in round particles form.
On interaction with water (dissolution), the rounded particles will be converted to
cylindrical ones.
Particles coalesce to form a bloby structure while
going down in the water.
Then the blob will settle down to fill up
the canal bed to avoid seepage.

I tried metaballs, searched on web but I’m getting no idea how to animate it in a simplest way. Help would be appreciated! Thanks

